# Unable to SSH into server until I've pinged it

Tags: 18.04, ssh

I have this interesting issue where I am unable to ssh into my server running bionic beaver unless I ping it first.  I ran into this issue on another server about a year ago running ubuntu 16, but I fixed it and didn't keep any notes on the problem because I thought it was a weird, one off issue.  In that situation, I wasn't able to access any of the services, such as ssh and web, until I had a constant ping going.  The kicker is that one of my other Ubuntu servers is able to ssh into this machine without any issues.  My workstation is an iMac running High Sierra, and yes, UFW has been disabled.

```
root@server:/var/log# ufw status
Status: inactive

root@server:/var/log# aptitude search ssh
p   erlang-ssh           - Erlang/OTP implementation of SSH protocol                                                                                      
p   libssh-4             - tiny C SSH library (OpenSSL flavor)                                                                                            
p   libssh-dev           - tiny C SSH library. Development files (OpenSSL flavor)                                                                         
p   libssh-doc           - tiny C SSH library. Documentation files                                                                                        
p   libssh-gcrypt-4      - tiny C SSH library (gcrypt flavor)                                                                                             
p   libssh-gcrypt-dev    - tiny C SSH library. Development files (gcrypt flavor)                                                                          
i   openssh-client       - secure shell (SSH) client, for secure access to remote machines                                                                
i   openssh-server       - secure shell (SSH) server, for secure access from remote machines                                                              
i   openssh-sftp-server  - secure shell (SSH) sftp server module, for SFTP access from remote machines                                                    
i   ssh                  - secure shell client and server (metapackage)                                                                                   
v   ssh-client           -                                                                                                                                
i   ssh-import-id        - securely retrieve an SSH public key and install it locally                                                                     
v   ssh-server           -                       

root@server:/var/log# aptitude show ssh
Package: ssh                      
Version: 1:7.6p1-4ubuntu0.2
State: installed
Automatically installed: no
Priority: optional
Section: net
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: all
Uncompressed Size: 106 k
Depends: openssh-client (>= 1:7.6p1-4ubuntu0.2), openssh-server (>= 1:7.6p1-4ubuntu0.2)
PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.17.5)

imac:~ iMac$ ssh -vvv administrator@server
OpenSSH_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to server port 22.
ssh: connect to host server port 22: Operation timed out
```

Any thoughts on why I would have difficulties getting into this machine from my Mac?

Comment: I have another Ubuntu server setup that is able to ssh into it without any issues.  In fact I was using that server to get the details I included in my initial post.

Comment: If you add the host and IP address to the `/etc/hosts` on the Mac, does it still require you to ping the server before you can ssh to it?

Comment: Modifying /etc/hosts doesn't make any difference on the client side.  Still receive a time out.

Comment: That's what is throwing me off here since ssh should be the same across the systems as far as the protocol itself goes.  Since your other Ubuntu server can ssh to it without a problem is why I was thinking the Mac might be.  Can the Mac ssh to the other Ubuntu host without pinging it?

Comment: Yep.  I have two other Ubuntu machines running and can connect to them with no problems.  Trust me, this issue is mind boggling and I had fixed it on a demo server I setup about a year ago, I just have no clue what I modified on the server to fix the problem.

Comment: That really is mind boggling.  +1 for visual here.  I do have a hybrid network with a Mac and Ubuntu servers but I have not seen why a setting would block being able to ssh to a server until you ping it.  Unfortunately, I wouldn't be much help from here.   Hopefully someone here might have stumbled across this before.  More upvotes, more visual.  Sorry, I wish I was more help from here.

Comment: I did have one thought here though, since you can ssh to the other servers from the Mac, look in the `/etc/ssh/` folder on those servers at the `sshd_config` and see what the differences are between the systems you can ssh to and the one that you cannot.

Comment: I've been comparing things between my test server and this new one.  I had just compared the netplan config, and check to see if I did anything in interfaces.  I'll check sshd_config between the two.

edit: no differences between the two.

Comment: Could it be something to do with wake on lan functionality?? Perhaps the mac thinks the server is offline for some reason and doesn't acknowledge it until it sees the successful ping. Do you see anything resembling an incoming connection in any of the logs on Ubuntu when you do try to ssh into it???

Comment: auth.log and syslog do not show anything regarding my connection attempt.  I tested that earlier by tailing the log as I attempted to connect.

Comment: Have you tried connecting with `ssh -vvv user@server` for the one you have to ping to?  If you can, edit your question with the output of the `ssh -vvv user@server` command but block out any personal identifying info.

Comment: Added output of ssh -vvv to my main post.  New development, one of my other Ubuntu servers is not able to connect to this machine either via SSH or CIFS.  SSH gets the same time out message, and the mount returns:  
`mount error(6): No such device or address`

Comment: Is there a way that you can make hook up the Mac or the other server in question to the same switch that this server is on?  You could eliminate your managed switch as being the problem.  Unfortunately, I have no clue how your network is laid out, these are only guesses.  Maybe this also might be good to ask at the https://ubuntuforums.org/ where you can get into full discussions about settings, etc.

Comment: I've checked everything I can think of on the network level; deleted arp entry on our firewall and the 1 managed switch that we have didn't have an arp entry for that server.  We're a small company, so the network isn't that complex; just unmanaged switches providing additional connectivity where it's needed.  This would normally be an inconvience for my machine, but seeing that it's my server that stores backups, and one of my other servers can't connect, this has become an even larger issue.  I'll update this thread with anything I find.

Comment: Also, now have the server hooked up to the same switch that my Mac is using and no change.  I'll see if giving that switch a boot may fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't clarify whether or not this happens locally on same lan, subnet or something else. If this happens locally it could be your SSH request doesn't reach the host due to bad switching or bad numbers in an ARP table somewhere. I would make sure to clear whatever tables client side and on hardware along the way. Make sure it's not networking before spending too much time debugging the server. (note: I really wanted to write this as a comment, but that wasn't possibly)

Comment: All of the connections are on the local LAN.  I have deleted the arp entries for this machine on my local Mac, and on our Firewall.  We only have 1 managed switch, of which I don't have admin access.  I'll get with the person who manages that device later to see about deleting some arp entries.

Comment: Try running tcpdump on the server while running the SSH command from your client to check if the server receives any packages from your mac. If the package never reaches the server you can rule out server issue. If it reaches you have to do some server debugging.

Comment: Good call.  I ran `tcpdump -s 0 <ipAddress>` and the server sees the connection attempts.  It could be a DNS issue as I'm seeing a DNS name that hasn't been used in a long time.

Comment: Fixed the DNS thing, but still no connection.  Ubuntu server sees the connection attempts from my local machine, local machine gets a time out.

Comment: Ended up being network related. Glad it worked out in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am the dumb.  It turns out that I used the wrong subnet CIDR when I was configuring the IP address, I used 24 instead of 23 so only machines with our .2.x subnet were able to connect and anything outside of that got denied.  I wasn't able to make the connection as to why certain machines wer able to connect to it and others weren't until my supervisor tried it from one of his servers and asked "could it be that only certain subnets can connect".  Light bulb went off, I changed the subnet value, and now I can connect.

Thanks everyone for attempting to help me.  TL:DR, check your subnet in netplan and make sure it's correct.  @wolfenstein87 are the dumb.